# Running into a missing right parenthesis error in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my query:

```
SELECT s.sname,
       s.deptid
FROM   student s
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ((SELECT *
                    FROM   class c)
                   EXCEPT
                   (SELECT c1.room
                    FROM   class c1,
                           enrolled e
                    WHERE  s.snum = e.snum
                           AND e.cname LIKE c1.cname))
GROUP  BY s.sname,
          s.deptid;
```

My error is

```
EXCEPT
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Not sure why as I seem to have the right amount of left and right parenthesis. I've tried moving everything to the where not exists line but get the same error.

Comment: there is no `except` in oracle. use `minus` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have tagged this `sqlplus` I assume you're using Oracle.  The `EXCEPT` keyword does not exist in Oracle; the equivalent is `MINUS`.  I think in this case the parser is seeing `EXCEPT` as an alias for the subquery preceding it, then expecting the parenthetical expression to be closed.

Try replacing `EXCEPT` with `MINUS` and see what result you get.  There could still be other syntax errors, the nesting is a little hard to follow.

Comment: For starts, the number of fields that should match on both querys. +1 for the catch.

Comment: Yeah, most likely should replace the `SELECT *` with `SELECT c.room`

Comment: Normally in an anti-join, the fields listed in the inner select are irrelevant...  which is why I'm sort of confused when I look at the code

Comment: Thanks! All your responses helped me figure out what was wrong.